# Change value of cell based on its on value

Tags: excel

I was wondering how to make it so if i put say 1 in cell a1 then the value of cell a1 will change.

I want it to make the value of a1 into 10 if 1 is inputed.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: You want "Conditional formatting"

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(A, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        A.Value = 10
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!